# How to show multiple Listview in one xml file?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to show multiple files in one XML file? This is like having a pane with two ListViews, one on the left and one on the right. I tried to set one ListView's `android:gravity` to the left and the other to the right. I have also tried using LinearLayout and creating two RelativeLayouts on it but it still doesn't do anything.

Any links, comments, suggestions or sample codes are much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative layout.  Then have the left one align to the parent's left edge, and the right one layout_toRightOf the left list.

Comment: Sir, I have tried that but still the left listview only shows. Maybe I have implemented it wrongly. Could you show me some codes, links or examples about this?..By the way sir, the listviews I want to show are the same. Thank you for your response, gladly appreciated it..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple side by side layout with each view taking up half the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sir, thank you for your response and I appreciated it but, when i try those set of codes it displays still one listview. Sorry maybe the question is not specific, the two list views that I want to show are the same.

Comment: Are you adding this to an existing layout? This layout works fine if used by itself. If you are adding it to additional items it may be breaking things

Comment: What do you mean "the two list views that I want to show are the same." Why have two list views that are the same?

Comment: I mean the same because things I want to show are files. On the left view I will show folders while on the right i will show files such as .txt, .ppt, .jpeg so on and so forth.

Comment: Ah understood. Are you using my exact layout without changes? I say this because I can confirm this layout works fine

Comment: yes sir.  when i use this layout it only show one listview. Thanks for the response

Comment: And you're 100% sure you're populating both? Have you looked at this in a layout editor? This is what shows: http://i.imgur.com/PkAQ1YH.jpg Are you modifying the layout in code, maybe?

Comment: In the layout editor it shows two listviews but when i try to run the app it only shows one listview.

Comment: @p0p0ts - does the one listview that's showing fill the entire screen? or does it only fill 50% ?

Comment: is only show 50% of the screen . Thank you for helping me sir, I really appreciated it

Comment: if it shows only 50% of the screen it means the 2nd list is there it's just not being populated by data

Comment: yes I guess, the second screen is there but it doesn't show up and maybe that's the problem but how to populate the data?